# How to read json POST value in php

Tags: php, json, extjs

I have Extjs grid with row editing plugin when add new grid row data After save data post value look like bellow image please tell how to read these post value using php

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$json = file_get_contents('php://input');
$input_data = json_decode($json, TRUE);
```